# Sort data frame by column of numbers

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to sort a data frame by a column of numbers and I get an alphanumeric sorting of the digits instead. If the data frame is converted to a matrix, the sorting works.

```
df[order(as.numeric(df[,2])),]

   V1 V2
1  a  1
3  c 10
2  b  2
4  d  3

> m <- as.matrix(df)
> m[order(as.numeric(m[,2])),]

      V1  V2  
[1,] "a" "1" 
[2,] "b" "2" 
[3,] "d" "3" 
[4,] "c" "10"
```

Comment: You may have a `factor` column.  Try `df[order(as.numeric(as.character(df[,2]))),]`

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: You can check akrun's theory using the ever-useful `str` function. Try it out on your data.frame and maybe post the restults.

Comment: @akrun Thank you, this worked

Comment: you need to use stringsAsFactors=FALSE when you build your data.frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
V1 <- letters[1:4]
V2 <- as.character(c(1,10,2,3))
df <- data.frame(V1,V2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df[order(as.numeric(df[,2])),]
```

gives

```
  V1 V2
1  a  1
3  c  2
4  d  3
2  b 10
```

But

```
V1 <- letters[1:4]
V2 <- as.character(c(1,10,2,3))
df <- data.frame(V1,V2)
df[order(as.numeric(df[,2])),]
```

gives

```
  V1 V2
1  a  1
2  b 10
3  c  2
4  d  3
```

which is due to factors.

thanks to the commentators akrun and Imo.  Inspect each of the two dfs with str(df).

Also, there is more detail given the factor() function help menu.  Scroll down to 'Warning' for more details of the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be a little more specific about what's your intial dataframe ?
Because by running this code :

```
df<-data.frame(c("a","b","c","d"),c(1,2,10,3))
colnames(df)<-c("V1","V2")

#print(df)

df.order<-df[order(as.numeric(df[,2])),]

print(df.order)
```

I get the right answer :

```
  V1 V2
1  a  1
2  b  2
4  d  3
3  c 10
```

Answer (score -2):

Edit:

The column values might be being treated as factors.

Try forcing to character and then integer.

Example copy and pasted from console:

```
> Foo <- data.frame('ABC' = c('a','b','c','d'),'123' = c('1','2','10','3'))
> Foo[order(as.integer(as.character(Foo[,2]))),]
  ABC X123
1   a    1
2   b    2
4   d    3
3   c   10
```

Comment: This leads to the same result. I think this is the reason you received a downvote.

Comment: Thanks, I just assumed that would work. Tested it and figured out how to do it. Thanks for pointing this out.